# Ensuring Type Safety in function signature: Matching values

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I want to setup a config object that has a format method.

I can not seem to get type checking on the argument for the format method

```js
export interface Config<D, ConfigId extends keyof D> {
  id: ConfigId
  format?: (value: D[ConfigId]) => any
}

type Data = {testA: number, testB: string}

const configObjs: readonly Config<{testA: number, testB: string}, keyof Data>[] = [
  {
    id: 'testA',
    format: (value) => {
      return value
    },
  },

]
```

I have tried a good bit. Can not get anything working.

I am expecting/wanting the arg in the format method in the above example to only be a number.

Here is a typescript playground idk how long they last but:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgYQiXQQHMAeAEQBoCiTSBJAEzlFSWYGc4BrYAJ4R0cSgD44AbwBQcRMwBcdYmRay46aAFtMMAPxKAFADdMAGwCuwJZQDahFU2YBdAJRwAvBMxIB0gL7S0jACYHiUupieUqhcMACCSkgWWgBGaLSxMABCSnFQyKSB0thEcXCljgDyqQBWXEpQwJjMRGYCygzkklmJcMlpGXBZuXD5hf60-EIiETCYYrbO0bbqMnJyCIpwAOS9O9TqcppQOjBGppbA7l5SRxtNMBZQSHCXVveT6l-SztJAA

Comment: Why would you expect the `value` parameter of `format()` in `configObjs` to be `number`? `keyof {testA: number, testB: number}[keyof Data]` clearly looks up both values of `testA` and `testB` which is `string | number`.

Comment: I want to be able to set an id ('testA') which then dictates the type of the format arg

Comment: Seems like you want `Config` to be a *distributive object type* as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mLOXeN) so that unions in the second type argument become unions in the result. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yup @jalz, that was it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `Config<D, K>` to be *distributive over [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) in `K`*.  Meaning that, for example, `Config<D, K1 | K2 | K3>` should expand out to `Config<D, K1> | Config<D, K2> | Config<D, K3>`, where each key in `K` has its own object type, so that the `id` and `value` will match in each union member.  But right now you're getting a single object type with a union `id` and a union `value` callback parameter, which mixes instead of matches.

There are a few ways to turn a non-distributive type into a distributive one. When you're distributing over *keys* or *keylike types*, I usually use what's called a *distributive object type* as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  It involves making a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over the keys and then immediately [indexing into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) it with the keys to get a union result.  So if `F<K>` is non-distributive in `K`, you can write `{[P in K]: F<P>}[K]}` to get the distributive version.

For your example then, that looks like

```
type Config<D, K extends keyof D> = { [P in K]: {
  id: P
  format?: (value: D[P]) => any
} }[K]
```

Note that this is a [`type` alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) and not an [`interface`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces), because interfaces can't be unions.

Let's test it out:

```
type Data = { testA: number, testB: string }

type Test = Config<Data, keyof Data>;
/* type Test = {
    id: "testA";
    format?: ((value: number) => any) | undefined;
} | {
    id: "testB";
    format?: ((value: string) => any) | undefined;
} */
```

Looks good. Now `Config<Data, keyof Data>` is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) of the shape you want, and so inside

```
const configObjs: readonly Config<Data, keyof Data>[] = [
  {
    id: 'testA',
    format: (value) => {
      //     ^?(parameter) value: number
      return value
    },
  },   
]
```

everything works, because the compiler can discriminate that union by the discriminant `id` property being `"testA"`, and the `value` callback parameter is [contextually](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) inferred as `number`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmAeAIgGigaSggA9gIEATAZygGsIQ4kosA+KAXigG8oBtAApQUCAgF0AXDwBQUYRSkDZUJHABOAWwCGwAPxSAFADctAGwCuEKVkFiAlJ3ZaEIaQF8obvvjHTpoSBYdLU4eKDIqYABBKQRzDQAjCDU8COAAISlItRE0Tz8A6AAVCEjQ+GR0bGC8ekZmLGDWAG5pAHoAKnDwYtLgUO5lORQFKAAiNKix1rk5VU0dfSgDYzNLWPiktQcOJxcHAB8oc0oIVAQIClaPI8HZ+SkJvvTpoZV1bT1DVYsrKGzcjs9iBDsdTudLtcoB02n4AMaIMoIypoADyCQAVlQpGoIFoKIhTCBYIhUJhGsAtLUGEwgpTWHwxKE+Mo7rMRlIAOSTTk4N7zT6GEy-IEye5yNptcUAPV0BjAWjUWg0EDI2ygwvWUDiiWSbzkuOA5jUok1EDebj5cktfl8QA)